# Can't get nodemon to work within a docker container

Tags: docker, nodemon

OK, I ran out of ideas now. I am trying to get nodemon to work in a dockerized (Docker Toolbox, Win 8.1) simple nodejs app.

**file structure**

[image: file structure]

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:latest
USER root
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g nodemon
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "npm", "run", "devStart" ]
```

**script**

```
"devStart": "nodemon --ext ejs,js,json,css --watch server --watch views server/server.js",
```

**-it output**

[image: it output]

Everything seems to match, but when I edit a partial/view nodemon does not restart.
Tried with nodemon as production (ie. not dev) dependency and then `npx nodemon...` - wouldn't work either.

Comment: Maybe have a look at `pm2`? It's a great process manager for nodejs in production. It is more stable and it does watch file changes.